# MongoDB field-array searching (C#, How to?)

Tags: c#, search, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Please tell me how make search by fields-arrays? I have some fields of type `List<Int64>`. For example first document has field-array with numbers [1,2,3,4] and second document has such field with numbers [4,5,6,7].

I want to find documents where my field consists 3 and 4 numbers, so it is first document. 
I am looking for examples that are based on official MongoDB C# driver;)

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `Query.All()`. Code like this:

```
var array = new List<int>() {3, 4};
var query = Query.All("SomeArray", new BsonArray(array));
collection.Find(query);
```

The result of `Query.All` will all documents thats have nested array `SomeArray` with values `3 and 4`.

If you want `3 or 4` use `Query.In("SomeArray", new BsonArray(array))`

References to the documentation:
[$all](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all), [$in](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in)

Comment: Is this supported in the LINQ provider?

Comment: Old answer but note that "BsonArray.Create(array)" is obsolete. Current syntax is "new BsonArray(array)".

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of the C# driver you can use:

```
Query<MyType>.All(_ => _.MyPropertyName, array));
```